# Precise control of conversion in Coq

Tags: coq

I try to prove the following theorem in Coq:

```
Theorem simple :
    forall (n b:nat) (input output: list nat) , short (n::b::input) true (n::output) = None 
             -> short (b::input) false output = None.
```

with short as follows :

```
Fixpoint short (input: list nat) (starting : bool) (output: list nat) : option (list nat) :=
match input with
  | nil => match output with
                 | nil => Some nil
                 | y::r => None
           end
  | x::rest => match output with
                | nil => ...
                | y::r => if ( beq_nat x y ) then match (short rest false r) with
                                                   | None => if (starting) then match (short rest starting output) with
                                                                               | Some pp => Some (0 :: pp)
                                                                               | None => None
                                                                           end 
                                                            else None 
                                                   | Some pp => Some (x :: pp)
                                                   end
                        else ...
end.
```

The proof would be simple if I could control the conversion steps to start with

```
short (n::b::input) true (n::output)
```

and end up with something like:

```
match (short (b::input) false output) with
            | None => match (short rest starting output) with
                            | Some pp => Some (0 :: pp)
                            | None => None
                      end 
            | Some pp => Some (x :: pp)
end
```

I've tried this :

```
Proof.
  intros.
  cbv delta in H.
  cbv fix in H.
  cbv beta in H.
  cbv match in H.
  rewrite Nat.eqb_refl in H.
...
```

but it seems that rewrite if doing more than a rewrite and performs a conversion I can't fold again to the desired form...

Any idea how this conversion can be done ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cbn` tactic looks like it does a decent job here:

```
Theorem simple :
    forall (n b:nat) (input output: list nat) , short (n::b::input) true (n::output) = None 
             -> short (b::input) false output = None.
Proof.
  intros.
  cbn in *.
  rewrite Nat.eqb_refl in H.
  match goal with | |- ?t = _ => set (x := t) in * end.
  destruct x.
  all: congruence.
Qed.
```

In general, I would advise against `cbv` unless you want to really get eg a boolean. But if you want to do "just a bit of unfolding" `cbn` or `simpl` are usually better behaved.

Comment: Your solution works with the match goal, but I don't think the same approach could be used for the similar following theorem : Theorem other :
    forall (n b:nat) (input output) , (exists p, short (n::b::input) false (n::output) = Some p)
             -> (exists p', short (b::input) false output = Some p').

Comment: I think it does (actually, I just did). You have to use a somewhat more complex `match goal`, but otherwise something similar can be done. Although I think I would advise trying to cut your complex function into smaller pieces if that is possible, in order to have a more factored reasoning and avoid having to use such ugly `match goal`.